# Is there a function similar to ArrayFind from ColdFusion 9 in ColdFusion 8?

Tags: arrays, coldfusion

I was talking with another fellow programmer at work and we use ColdFusion. He is telling me simply look for a value in an array I have to do a whole loop? Is it true there is no function in ColdFusion 8 to simply look for a value in an Array?

Comment: realizing the question is about CF8, if anyone stumbles here from the searches, we've now got https://cfdocs.org/arrayfind implemented :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`arrayFind()` doesn't exist in ColdFusion 8. However, you don't need to loop. There are two ways:

Take advantage of the fact that ColdFusion arrays implement the interface [java.util.List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html):

```
<cfset valueToFind = 1>
<cfset array = [1,2,3]>
<!--- add one because CF does 1 based vs. Java 0 based arrays --->
<cfset position = array.indexOf(valueToFind) + 1>
```

Use list operations:

```
<cfset valueToFind = 1>
<cfset array = [1,2,3]>
<cfset position = listFind(arrayToList(array), valueToFind)>
```

The first (Java List) method is faster.

Comment: Yes, those are the same two methods mentioned below. (A third method is obviously to loop through the array). BTW: It is worth noting the java method is *not* documented and can behave differently than you might expect. So use it at your own risk.

Comment: @Leigh: what's the unexpected behavior for the Java approach?

Comment: @orangepips: if he knew, then it wouldn't be unexpected :)  I think his point is that if it's not documented, anything about it can change in the next CF update/version.  Or it could even go away completely.  That'd be pretty unexpected, eh? :)

Comment: @charliegrief: fair enough, but ColdFusion docs go so far to say that Arrays are represented internally by java.util.Vector, which implements java.util.List. I'd call that documented. Link: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7884.html

Comment: @orangepips: true.  but Adobe doesn't explicitly document the underlying methods.  I'm not saying they shouldn't be used if available, but the caveat is worth being aware of (IMO).

Comment: @orangepips - The java method matches on object type and value. So a search for the value/type 1(integer) is *not* the same as 1(string). So if you do not know exactly what object types you are dealing with, the results may surprise you. The java method is also case sensitive. But the former is the biggest gotcha.

Comment: @Leigh: makes sense, +1 to your answer then for something I hadn't thought about.

Comment: Note also that in Open BlueDragon, CFML arrays apparently don't have an indexOf method, at least as of 2.0.2. And not to point out the obvious, but the list approaches rely on using a delimiter that's not present in the data.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK there is no *documented* arrayFind function in CF8. There is an arrayFind [function at cflib.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20120106223425/http://www.cflib.org/udf.cfm/arrayfind) that takes advantage of some undocumented 
java functionality. See also [How do I find a value in an array?](http://web.archive.org/web/20110222202308/http://www.coldfusioncookbook.com/entry/35/How-do-I-find-a-value-in-an-array):

> ... ColdFusion arrays are an
>   implementation of java lists (java.util.List). So all the Java list
>   methods are available for CF arrays.
>
> So to search an array all you need to do is add the appropriate
>   method. For example, given this array:
>
> `<cfset arry = listToArray("tom, dick, harry, phred")>`
>
> You can do a find like this: `<cfset findValue = arry.indexOf("harry")>`
>
> would return a 2 - the index value of harry in the array.
>
> indexOf returns the index value of the item in the array.

**NB: Be aware that unlike CF methods, the java method matches on both the value AND type**. So searching for the number 1 (integer/double/etcetera) is NOT the same as searching for "1" (string). If you do not know exactly what object types you are dealing with, the results may surprise you.

Take these two examples:

```
<cfscript>
// numeric searches are sensitive to type
arry = listToArray("2,4,6");
writeOutput('<br>indexOf("6") =  '&  arry.indexOf("6"));
writeOutput('<br>indexOf( val(6) )=  '&  arry.indexOf(val(6)));

// string searches are case sensitive
arry = listToArray("tom,dick,harry,phred");
writeOutput("<br>indexOf(harry) =  "&  arry.indexOf("harry"));
writeOutput("<br>indexOf(HaRry) = "&  arry.indexOf("HaRry"));
</cfscript>
```

A search for `"6"` yields different results than `val(6)`

- indexOf("6") = 2
- indexOf( val(6) )= -1

.. and a string search for `"harry"` yields different results than `"HaRry"`

- indexOf(harry) = 2
- indexOf(HaRry) = -1

So when using java methods, know what you are getting ... and what you are not.

Comment: Unfortunately both links you reference are no longer available. So this answer doesn't provide any benefit to future users. :(  Just wanted to alert you to that. Cheers.

Comment: Done. Replaced broken links with web.archive.org copy, and added snippet of content from linked article. Thanks for the heads up @AnilNatha.

Comment: Anytime! Thanks for updating the post.

Answer (score -1):

Being the author of the UDF you found, I'd like to point out that the ArrayFind UDF uses CF's underlying java foundations, I highly doubt that Adobe would change that fundamental aspect of CF. Also this is fully documented in Rupesh Kumar's (one of Adobe's CF programmers) blog at:
http://coldfused.blogspot.com/2007/01/extend-cf-native-objects-harnessing.html

regards,
larry