# ColdFusion 8 ArrayFind Substitute

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I have an array that has a structure of ImageID and Custnum.
I need to find a particular ImageID and retrieve the Custnum for it. 
I’m using ColdFusion 8 which does not have an ArrayFind command. 
How would I do this without looping through each item? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question may be answered to a point here "[Is there a function similar to ArrayFind from ColdFusion 9 in ColdFusion 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337509/is-there-a-function-similar-to-arrayfind-from-coldfusion-9-in-coldfusion-8)" but I don't see any other way apart from looping.

You can always create and use an UDF but it would have to use looping.

Why exactly you don't want to use looping anyway? Do you have that many elements in the array? Just remember to use `cfbreak` after finding your element to stop going through the rest of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Given your situation, I don't think `arrayFind()` would help you much anyhow, as to find something with `arrayFind()`, you need to know exactly what you're looking for anyhow. And whilst you know your `ImageID`, you don't know the `Custnum` associated with it (hence your underlying problem).

There's nothing native in CF which can help you here, but there's a UDF on [CFLib](http://www.cflib.org/) - [`structFindKeyWithValue()`](http://www.cflib.org/udf/structFindKeyWithValue) which'll do the trick.

It's written for CF9, but is easily backported to CF8. The modified, CF8-friendly version - is in the example below:

```
<cfscript>
a = [
    {ImageID=1, Custnum=1},
    {ImageID=2, Custnum=2},
    {ImageID=3, Custnum=3},
    {ImageID=4, Custnum=4}
];
testStruct = {a=a};
result = structFindKeyWithValue(testStruct, "ImageID", 2, "ONE");

function structFindKeyWithValue(struct, key, value, scope){
    var keyResult = false;
    var valueResult = [];
    var i = 0;

    if (!isValid("regex", arguments.scope, "(?i)one|all")){
        throw(type="InvalidArgumentException", message="Search scope #arguments.scope# must be ""one"" or ""all"".");
    }
    keyResult = structFindKey(struct, key, "all");
    for (i=1; i <= arrayLen(keyResult); i++){
        if (keyResult[i].value == value){
            arrayAppend(valueResult, keyResult[i]);
            if (scope == "one"){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return valueResult;
}
</cfscript>
<cfdump var="#result#">
```

Note that because it's a *stuct* function, you need to wrap your data in a struct first. Other than that it's fairly straight fwd.

Comment: Thanks this is helpful! How then would I use this script for an array within an array. http://www.artphotoindex.com/api/exhibitions-new/utilities/test-array.cfm

Comment: No different. structFindKey() / ~Value() will traverse as many levels of array as necessary to locate the structs they inspect.

Comment: Hmm. I tried it with no results. Could you check the link to see what I might be doing wrong? http://artphotoindex.com/api/exhibitions-new/utilities/test-array.cfm

Comment: All I can see I the output, which doesn't help me guess what code you're running. Can you put your code in a gist or pastebin or something?

Comment: That code's not much use to me mate... I don't have access to your DB, so I can't run that code to see what I get. Can you pls provide some *stand alone* code? But superficially, it looks like it's all legit. So is a bit puzzling.